# Pixel values in an image

Tags: gimp

I created a grayscale image using lodepng library. In windows explorer, when I right click the image and go to Properties->Details, the field "Bit depth" has a value of 16. However, when I open the image in gimp and use [Pointer Dialog](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-pointer-info-dialog.html), the value is between 0 and 255, which is only 8 bits. How do I see the 16 bit value?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Which version of GIMP are you using?  Only 2.10.x supports 16 bit images.  To check bit depth, in the main menu click *Image* and mouse over *Precision*. Bit depth [should be displayed](https://imgur.com/WxZ3dmF).

Comment: When bit depth is 16bit - you should see RGB values between 0 and 65,535 with the pointer. [see example](https://imgur.com/bkJAJT4).  If you share the image, I could take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you for the comments @BillyKerr. I am using version 2.8.8. I will upgrade my version and see.

Comment: I upgraded to 2.10.x and now I am able to see higher values.